# Joining objects that have displacement modifiers

Tags: modeling, modifiers, objects

I have a problem with joining three objects together. On the model of a dinosaur I have a displacement map with a texture on it:

[image: Before]
When I try to join the eye, teeth and the model together (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>) it comes up like this:

[image: After]

......I think its because of the displacement modifier, it applies to the two other objects and creates this weird thing... Does anyone know what to do with this? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If that's because of **DIsplacement** modifier, you can assign all the verts of the dinosaur mesh to a new vertex group and select that group in modifier's settings. This will make it affect only on those vertices. Aside from that, you could apply modifier before joining objects.

Comment: @MrZak Are you going to write up an answer?

Comment: @MrZak Thanks for help, it actually worked :D

Comment: @DalekMaker No, I'm pretty sure the OP did that already. Probably the answer needs some editing though to be more useful.

Comment: @MrZak Ah, okay :( I can try and fix it up a bit :) OP: Generally you want to wait 24 or so hours before creating an answer that uses the same technique found in the comments. Why? Well, you take credit away from the person who originally mentioned it, and you steal their rep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, you need to assign all the verts of the dinosaur mesh to a new vertex group and select that group in modifier's settings. This will make it affect only on those vertices.

Answer (score 0):

You could try applying the displacement texture before joining them. It just depends on whether or not you'll need to edit the texture later...